# XML validation against restriction on XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

How would I go about specifying in an XSD that the step/@nextTask value is only valid if it does not matches a value of a task/@name, in this XML document:

```
<tasks>
    <task name="task-12">
        <step>Open folder</step>
        <step nextTask="task-14">Delete contents.</step>
    </task>
    <task name="task-13">
        <step nextTask="task-16">Create new folder folder</step>
    </task>
    <task name="task-14">
        <step>Move files into folder.</step>
    </task>
</tasks>
```

Comment: Mr. alexwlchan, can you plz give answer?

Answer (score 1):

It's rather clumsy, but you could use a uniqueness constraint:

```
<xs:element name="task">
  <xs:unique>
    <xs:selector xpath=".|step"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@*"/>
  </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

The clumsiness is because you can't name two different attributes for the two different elements, so this falls apart as soon as additional attributes can appear on these elements.

A better solution is XSD 1.1 assertions:

```
<xs:element name="task">
  ...
  <xs:assert test="not(@name = step/@nextTask)"/>
</xs:element>
```

XSD 1.1 is currently implemented in Saxon, Xerces, and Altova.

Comment: can we done by giving ID to task/@name and then how we refer the value of ID?

Comment: Thanks Mr. kay. I am using JAVA for validation which is not accepting name space of xsd1.1.     For uniqueness i can give ID to the task/@name but how we can test that it should not match the value of step/@nextTask. Whether in any way it is possible in xsd1.1 or not. plz

Comment: IDs will not help you because you want uniqueness within the whole document. If you are using Java then you have two XSD 1.1 processors available: Xerces and Saxon. I don't know what you mean by "namespace of xsd 1.1" - there is no such thing.